# RestSharp: get JSON string after deserialization?

Tags: json, deserialization, restsharp

using RestSharp is there a way to get the raw json string after it has been deserialized into an object? I need that for debugging purposes.

I'd like to see both the deserialized object and the originally received json string of that object. It's part of a much bigger json string, an item in an array and I only need that specific item json code that's got deserialized into the object.

Answer (score 0):

To help you out this should work, this is a direct example of some of my work, so your's might be a bit different.

```
private void restClient()
        {
            string url = "http://apiurl.co.uk/json";
            var restClient = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("apikey", "xxxxxxxxxx");

            restClient.ExecuteAsync<Entry>(request, response =>
            {
                lstboxtop.Items.Add(response.Content);
            });
        }
```

The line lstboxtop is a listbox and using the response.content will literally print the whole api onto your app, if you call it first that would be what you are looking for